# MySQL: Not unique table/alias: 'favourites'

Tags: mysql

The error I'm getting is:

> Not unique table/alias: 'favourites'

I apologise for the reasonably intense query(!):

```
    SELECT code.id AS codeid, code.featured AS featured, code.title AS codetitle, code.summary AS codesummary, code.author AS codeauthor, code.date, code.challengeid,
    ratingItems.*, FORMAT((ratingItems.totalPoints / ratingItems.totalVotes), 1) AS rating,
    code_tags.*, tags.*,
    users.firstname AS authorname, users.id AS authorid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ', ') AS taggroup,
    COUNT(DISTINCT comments.codeid) AS commentcount,
    favourites.id, favourites.code_id, favourites.user_id

    FROM (code)
    JOIN code_tags ON code_tags.code_id = code.id
    JOIN tags ON tags.id = code_tags.tag_id
    JOIN users ON users.id = code.author
    LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.codeid = code.id
    LEFT JOIN ratingItems ON uniqueName = code.id
    LEFT JOIN favourites ON favourites.user_id = 10
    LEFT JOIN favourites ON favourites.code_id = code.id

    GROUP BY code_id
    ORDER BY date desc
```

What am I doing wrong? I really can't understand it...

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: Can you explain what your query is supposed to do? Why you want to join with the favourites table twice? What is the primary key of the favourites table?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't very clear! It basically selects data - code submissions - to populate a list with, but only if the user who's profile this is being displayed on has favourited them. I've solved it now though thanks to your answer! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you only want to join with the favourites table once but with two conditions. If so use this:

```
LEFT JOIN favourites ON  favourites.user_id = 10
                     AND favourites.code_id = code.id
```

If you do actually want to join with this table twice then you need to give it two different aliases:

```
LEFT JOIN favourites f1 ON f1.user_id = 10
LEFT JOIN favourites f2 ON f2.code_id = code.id
```

Then in the SELECT list you instead of favourites you need to use either f1 or f2 as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Mark! That solved it. I didn't mean to join it twice - I'm a bit of a novice at SQL joins. Cheers!